# Javascript sometimes fails to show text in paragraphs until some javascript event is called

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm working on a large OpenGL tutorial site and a large part of its content is being retrieved via javascript. However, from time to time, loading the site results in weird javascript behavior, something I haven't been able to fix myself. I'm not sure you 'll be able to reproduce it instantly since the occurence seems a bit non-deterministic but the site's url is http://www.learnopengl.com.

If you open it often enough you'll eventually get the bugged page I'm experiencing. The content is loaded, but for some reason it fails to display any text that is not enclosed within a `<code>`, `<em>`, `<strong>` etc. tag (inline elements), so it still displays the content inside `<code></code>` tags for example, but fails to display all the text inside paragraphs.

It seems the issue only occurs when using Chrome. I'm not able to reproduce the behavior using Firefox and/or Internet explorer. Using Chrome I used the developer tools to check if any of the html was different, but everything is still the same. There were also no javascript errors to report in the console. Its behavior is strange since it seems to occur at random times.

Also, whenever the behavior occurs, as soon as I start using anything that uses javascript, the content restores again. For example, when clicking one of the menu buttons to the left, or hovering over certain content that activates a javascript hover event.

I'll post my header code here in case it might be of value:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Learn OpenGL . com, Tutorial resource for learning Modern OpenGL</title>
    <script>
      // Google Analytics code
      ...
    </script>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/hoverintent.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="layout.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js/styles/obsidian.css">
    <script src="js/highlight.pack.js"></script>    
    <script src="js/functions.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/mathjax/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML"></script>
    <script>hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();</script>
    <script>  
        // OnPopState only works in Chrome when loading the page, so this has to be done manually the first time.        
        $(document).ready(function() {
            LoadPage();
        });
        var initialized = false;
        window.onpopstate = function() {
            if(initialized)
                LoadPage();
            else
                initialized = true;
        };

        // Set up DISQUS
        var disqus_shortname = 'learnopengl';
        (function() {
            var dsq = document.createElement('script'); dsq.type = 'text/javascript'; dsq.async = true;
            dsq.src = '//' + disqus_shortname + '.disqus.com/embed.js';
            (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(dsq);
        })();   
   </script>        
</head>
```

And the `LoadPage()` function:

```
function LoadPage()
{
    if(window.location.hash)
    {
        var name = window.location.hash.substring(2);
        name = name.replace(/-/g," ");
        LoadContent(name, true, false);
    }
    else
        LoadContent("Index", true, false);     
}

function LoadContent(name, slide, changeURL)
{
    var postData = "content_name=" + name;
    $('#disqus_thread').hide();
    $('#content').fadeOut(slide? 250 : 0, function() {            
        $.post("content_load.php", postData, function(data) {
            $('#content').html(data);   
            $('#content').fadeIn(slide ? 250 : 0);                    
            // Check if data has been succesfully loaded, if so: change title bar as ajax hash fragment
            var title = $('#content-url').text();
            if(title.indexOf('404') == -1)
            {
                if(name != 'Index')
                    document.title = $('#content-title').text();
                title = title.replace(/ /g,"-");
                if(changeURL)
                {     
                    var link = '/';
                    if(name != "Index")
                        link = "#!" + title;
                    history.pushState({}, '', link);   
                }
                // Refresh syntax highlighting
                $('pre').each(function(i, e) {hljs.highlightBlock(e)});
                MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub]);       
                // Reset DISQUS
                DISQUS.reset({
                  reload: true,
                  config: function () {  
                    this.page.identifier = title;  
                    this.page.url = "http://www.learnopengl.com/" + title;
                  }
                });
                $('#disqus_thread').show();
                // Some post processing functions follow
                ...
            }
        });              
    });
}
```

I'm currently at a loss and I was hoping any of you could re-create the behavior and see anything weird pop up.

Comment: This is a question that could really benefit from a fiddle, or code updated to point to CDNs somewhere -- something that we could to to actually reproduce the issue.  As it is now, all we can do is stare at code.

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher: I understand the issue. The only way to reproduce it (as far as I know) is to just spam the link and see whenever the paragraph's text becomes invisible. I was hoping this was an issue some javascript experts might recognize, but apart from that I don't really know what more to post? I could post the content loading functions, but not sure if that would matter since content seems to load properly (content is there, just paragraph's text is not visible)?

Comment: I was hesitant to just spam the link you provided -- I know some hosting charges by the amount transferred.

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher: oh haha, I'm sorry. I didn't think about that. Yeah it's no problem to spam the link as long as you keep it under a thousand clicks ;). The error usually occurs every 10 site loads in my case.

Comment: 50 reloads in the latest versions of Chrome and IE... am not able to duplicate.  Symptoms would suggest that you have a race error on your local machine -- with some bit of coding running, expecting that something else has already happened.  Usually related to `onload` events.

Comment: Hmmm, weird. I must mention that the condition also happens on a different system, but that could be a coincidence. I'll edit the question to show the onload scripts as well.

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher Also something to note. I just re-tested it with firefox and internet explorer and it seems I'm not able to reproduce it on those browsers (it reproduced on those as well when I first started debugging this behavior, but appareantly it now only seems to happen on chrome.) I'll update the question.